# How to re-size polygon in jPanel?

Tags: java, graphics

I have to make a program that generates stars in random locations of random size. My code already plots the stars in random locations, but I can't manage to randomly change their sizes. I tried assigning a size factor to each point to alter the distance between them but the stars came out all messed up. Is there a scaling method I can use?

Here is what I have so far, it plots the stars in random locations.

```
  final int MID = WIDTH / 2;
  final int TOP = 50;
    
  //sky
  Color skyColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);
  page.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    
  //ground
  Color groundColor = new Color(95,95,95);
  page.setColor(groundColor);
  page.fillRect(0,HEIGHT-20,getWidth(),getHeight());
  
  
  //star
  for (int i = 1; i <= starCount; i++)
  
  {
     int ranLocX = gen.nextInt(700 - 100) + 100;
     int ranLocY = gen.nextInt(300 - 75) + 75;
     int ranSize = gen.nextInt(8 - 1) + 1;
     
     int sizeXA = (-10 * ranSize);
     int sizeXB = (10 * ranSize);
     int sizeXC = (-5 * ranSize);
     int sizeXD = (-10 * ranSize);
     int sizeXE = (-10 * ranSize);
     int sizeXF = (-10 * ranSize);
     
     int sizeYC = (10 * ranSize);
     int sizeYD = (-10 * ranSize);
     int sizeYE = (10 * ranSize);
     
     page.drawPolygon(new int[] {xa + ranLocX, xb + ranLocX, xc + ranLocX, xd + ranLocX, xe + ranLocX, xf + ranLocX}, new int[] {ya + ranLocY, yb + ranLocY, yc + ranLocY, yd + ranLocY, ye + ranLocY, yf + ranLocY}, 6);
     
     
  }
```

Comment: What is the actual shape of the stars?  If you're creating 5-point stars, use polar coordinates to define the five points and convert them to cartesian coordinates to plot.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Yes they are 5 point stars. Could you elaborate on how to use polar coordinates to define the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to change the size of a Polygon.  I drew squares but any Shape will work.

- just create a scale instance of an `AffineTransform` and use that to scale the Shape.
- I used `ThreadLocalRandom` to randomly choose the scale to be applied.  I always copy the original polygon(`template`) and then scale that.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Polygons extends JPanel {
      static int WIDTH = 500;
      static int HEIGHT = 500;
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      Polygon b =new Polygon();
      ThreadLocalRandom r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
      List<Shape> polys = new ArrayList<>();
      
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> new Polygons().start());
      }
      public void start() {
          f.add(this);
          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          f.pack();
          f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          f.setVisible(true);
          Polygon template = new Polygon();
          
              template.addPoint(0,0);
              template.addPoint(0,100);
              template.addPoint(100,100);
              template.addPoint(100,0);
          
//        AffineTransform rotate = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(72.), )
           
          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
              Polygon p = new Polygon(template.xpoints,template.ypoints, template.npoints);
              p.translate(r.nextInt(WIDTH), r.nextInt(HEIGHT));
              double scale = r.nextInt(10,90)/100.;
              AffineTransform scaleIt = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale,scale);
              
              polys.add(scaleIt.createTransformedShape(p));
              
          }
      }
      
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
      }
     
      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
          g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                  RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          for (Shape shape : polys) {
              g2d.draw(shape);
          }
      }
}
```

Here is something I wrote a long time ago to create a 5 point star.  It draws a single arm and then rotates 72 degrees and draws another, repeating the process.

Because it was written to allow the base to be changed, hence the star size, this might be as better option for scaling the size of your stars rather than using the `AffineTransform` mentioned above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

  // get the base of the next star between 5 and 29 inclusive                        
  int base = r.nextInt(5,30);
  Polygon star = createStar(base);

  // now randomly position it.                  
  star.translate(r.nextInt(0,400),r.nextInt(0,400));
  
  // and add to the list 
  polys.add(star);                                  
}
```

Creating a 5 point star

```
int startx = 250; // arbitrary starting points
int starty = 250;
public Polygon createStar(int armBase) {
    Polygon star = new Polygon();
    
    // The armBase is equal to one side of the inner
    // pentagon of the star
    
    // The height of the arm is the distance from the middle of the 
    // base to the tip of the stars arm. Since the tangent computes
    // ratio of the sides of a right triangle, multiplying by half
    // the base gives the other side, hence the height.
    int armHeight =
            (int) (armBase / 2 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(72)));
    
    // The center offset is the distance from the middle of a given
    // base to the center of the inner pentagon.
    int centerOffset =
            (int) (armBase / 2 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(54)));
    
    // this works by creating the first arm, rotating 72 degrees
    // and then adding the other two coodinates of succeeding arms.
    
    star.addPoint(startx, starty);
    star.addPoint(startx + armBase / 2, starty - armHeight);
    star.addPoint(startx + armBase, starty);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        rotatePolygon(-Math.PI / 5 * 2, startx + armBase / 2,
                starty + centerOffset, star);
        star.addPoint(startx + armBase / 2, starty - armHeight);
        star.addPoint(startx + armBase, starty);
    }
    star.npoints--;
    
    star.translate(-star.getBounds().x,-star.getBounds().y); 
    return star;
}

// This is general purpose rotation that rotates about a center
// point. This can be derived using the double angle identities of
// for sin and cosine.
private void rotatePolygon(double ang, double sx, double sy,
        Polygon poly) {
    for (int j = 0; j < poly.npoints; j++) {
        double x = poly.xpoints[j];
        double y = poly.ypoints[j];
        double xx = sx + (x - sx) * Math.cos(ang)
                - (y - sy) * Math.sin(ang);
        double yy = sy + (x - sx) * Math.sin(ang)
                + (y - sy) * Math.cos(ang);
        poly.xpoints[j] = (int) xx;
        poly.ypoints[j] = (int) yy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method you can use to create a `Shape` with any given number of points and radius:

```
 public static Shape radiusShape(int points, int... radii)
 {
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();

    for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
    {
        double radians = Math.toRadians(i * 360 / points);
        int radius = radii[i % radii.length];

        double x = Math.cos(radians) * radius;
        double y = Math.sin(radians) * radius;

        polygon.addPoint((int)x, (int)y);
    }

    Rectangle bounds = polygon.getBounds();
    polygon.translate(-bounds.x, -bounds.y);

    return polygon;
}
```

To create your 5 point star you would use code like:

```
Shape star = ShapeUtils.radiusShape(10, 30, 12);
```

It will create a star with 5 outer points and 5 inner points to give the star shape.

So to randomize the size of the star you would randomize the radius.

Check out [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more examples of the types of Shapes you can create using this method. The above `radiusShape(...)` method was taken from the `ShapeUtils` class found in the above link.

I would then suggest you create a custom class with the properties 1) Shape 2) Point so you can paint the Star at different locations on the panel. Then you create an ArrayList to hold instances of the class. In your painting method you iterate through this ArrayList to paint each Shape. The above link will also provide basic code for this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a GUI to draw one five-pointed star.

[image: Starry Nights]

Here's the complete runnable code.  I used polar coordinates to calculate the 10 points I needed to draw a star.  I guessed the fraction to get the intermediate points correct.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StarryNight2GUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new StarryNight2GUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Starry Night");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(new DrawingPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Color groundColor = new Color(95, 95, 95);
            g.setColor(groundColor);
            g.fillRect(0, getHeight() - 30, getWidth(), 30);
            
            Polygon polygon = createStar(new Point(320, 240), 80);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillPolygon(polygon);
        }
        
        private Polygon createStar(Point centerPoint, int radius) {
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
            // 72, 144, 216, 288, 360
            // 36, 108, 180, 252, 324
            // 54, 126, 198, 270, 342
            // 18, 54, 90, 126, 162, 198, 234, 270, 306, 342
            for (int angle = 18; angle < 360; angle += 72) {
                double r = 0.42 * radius;
                Point point = toCartesian(centerPoint, angle, r);
                polygon.addPoint(point.x, point.y);
                point = toCartesian(centerPoint, angle + 36, radius);
                polygon.addPoint(point.x, point.y);
            }
            
            return polygon;
        }
        
        private Point toCartesian(Point centerPoint, int angle, double radius) {
            double theta = Math.toRadians(angle);
            int x = centerPoint.x + (int) Math.round(Math.cos(theta) * radius);
            int y = centerPoint.y + (int) Math.round(Math.sin(theta) * radius);
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
        
    }

}
```